# Memset too slow on large data. Any alternatives?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, memset

I have a large `cv::Mat` with dimensions `(100,32768)`. I update it for every frame in a video stream. Before updating, I need to set everything back to zero so I execute

`memset(myMat.data,0,100*32768*sizeof(int))`

which takes 5ms on average.

Surprisingly(at least to me) in debug mode I get the same times, if not faster ones. While I'd appreciate an explanation as to why this is happening (google gives me loads of reasons so I will eventually figure it out), what I really need is an alternative faster solution. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are there any sections of the matrix that you can be certain were never set non-zero?  If so, you could avoid re-zeroing those sections and zero only the sections that might be non-zero.

Comment: So, that's 32 MB, multipled by `sizeof(int)`. This is going to be either 128 or 256 megabytes of RAM. If it takes this much time to clear 128 or 256 megabytes of memory, that I'm afraid that's how long it takes. That's it. There are no shortcuts through space and time, that your CPU can take in order to clear X amount of RAM faster than the hardware is capable of. If your car's top speed is 120 miles an hour, it will take you an hour to travel 120 miles. There's nothing you can do to make your car go faster than its engine can make it go. You can't make your CPU run faster than it can.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Sections no, but the data is quite sparse. I could try a solution of 100 unordered maps but accessing mat elements proved way faster. Besides that, I realized I can use a short integer instead but it still takes 2.5ms.

Comment: That seems way too slow. That's like 1.2MB in 5ms so like around 250MB/s. Even under extreme memory pressure that seems extremely slow for a modern system unless you're chronically swapping to disk. Did you try just making a simple for loop that sets all the values to 0?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Oh, so it comes down to that...Great.  By the way, my ram only has like 600 MB free at the moment. Will I have any luck if I close all my 2GB chrome tabs?

Comment: Oh, I was off by an order of magnitude. It's 12MiB. So 2500MB/s. Which might be the limit in some system if you're doing a lot of other stuff as well in other threads/processes. DDR3-800 is like 6400 MB/s total, but I would assume you have something faster.

Comment: FWIW I just tested the time it takes to memset() a `100*32768*4`-byte array on my 2018 Mac Mini (3.2GHz i7), and i measure around 4mS.  I suspect that's just the cost of touching so much RAM... perhaps you can hide the delay by doing double (or triple) buffering and zeroing out the buffers ahead of time, perhaps even in a separate thread?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That was very helpful. Yeah, I'll just have to find a way to hide the delay I guess. I could try a thread for sure. I don't know what buffering is but I'll have a look, thanks !

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner did you only memset it once after allocating uninitialized memory? The initial virtual memory page writes may be slower than successive ones

Comment: Another dumb idea (that might work if the data is very sparse) -- whenever you set a matrix cell to non-zero, add the x/y coordinates of that cell to a data-structure.  Then to clear the matrix you can just iterate over the data structure, setting the cells specified therein to zero; that way you only have to touch the memory that actually needs zeroing.  (if the data structure gets too large, you could store the coordinates of N-size blocks instead of individual coordinates, and trade off some accuracy for more compact storage)

Comment: @PeterT I did it over and over again in a `while(1)` loop, printing out the time taken after each iteration of the test.  I let it run for several hundred iterations and then eyeballed the results.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I did it many times but I think I allocate the memory again each time. Let me see how it goes if I allocate only once. As for keeping the coordinates, yes that's one thing I had in mind. I'm just worried it might be too slow making these coordinates or actually going through each non-zero element. But I've realized the data will be too sparse so I might have a chance. Specifically, each row of the 100 rows will have at most 2500 entries out of 32768.

Comment: Have you tried just freeing the memory and `calloc`ing a new buffer each time?  It might make things worse, I honestly don't know, but it's worth a try since it's such an easy solution… let the OS handle it for you :)

Comment: even on whatever cloud machines compiler explorer is running on I get like 12.2GB/s which is around DDR3-1600 speed, that seems a lot more reasonable than what you got. https://godbolt.org/z/9dWjq4PTM

Comment: does the array change completely in every frame? If not then I guess there are some ways to reuse it and just update the necessary parts like how video codecs work. And the reason you get the same speed for memset in both debug and release mode is because they're both the same optimized SIMD version, no one jumps into a library call and debug it so those functions can be optimized completely even in debug mode

Comment: memset is pretty well optimized and chances are high that you can't zero out the buffer faster. But in the first place, question why you need to zero it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DDR 4 3k ish caps out at a bit under 100 GB/s  DDR 3 800 is 6.4 GB/s.

Your speed is about 12 MB/5ms, or 2.4 GB/s.

So depending on your RAM, you might be near max speed for your hardware.  A factor of 2 ain't bad.

You are working on a modestly sparse array.  It is possible that a non contiguous buffer might be a better plan, depending on how your data is arranged.  Also, GPUs tend to have faster internal memory bandwidth than CPUs, moving your work there could help.

The problem could also be latency; maybe clearing one buffer in another thread while using another would help.

Massively reducing your memory usage, and making it more local, may have a larger impact than you expect.  It is plausible your non zeroing code is RAM speed constrained already.